# Getting segmentation fault after performing arithmetic on unsigned int

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, unsigned-integer, integer-arithmetic

The code is given below. I'm getting segmentation fault can't understand why. I think it's because of the arithmetic I'm doing on the variables t and k(both are unsigned int), can anyone explain why this segmentation fault is occurring.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    unsigned int n,k,q,i,t;
    scanf("%u %u %u",&n,&k,&q);
    unsigned int a[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%u",&a[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<q;i++)
    {
        scanf("%u",&t);
        if(t-k>0)
            printf("%u\n",a[t-k]);
        else
            printf("%u\n",a[t-k+n]);
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: concentrate here `if(t-k>0)`...hint: unsigned operation. consider t = 1, k = 2....

Comment: Thanks @SouravGhosh, got it.

Comment: This shows the importance of using your compiler's warnings properly.  Enable plenty of warnings, and it should tell you about comparing `unsigned` against zero.

Comment: @TobySpeight, `gcc -Wall -pedantic px.c` didn't issue a relative warning. Which flag should I use?

Comment: @gsamaras I thought that `-Wall -Wextra` might be enough, but I confess to not testing that.  So I might need to revise my comment - it would warn you if you'd tested `t-k>=0` as was obviously meant   ;-) since `a[0+n]` is out of range.

Comment: @TobySpeight, just tested, the flags do not issue a warning, sorry. :/

Comment: Instead of using unsigned int, I used long long int for variable k and t and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the problem is related to this if statement

```
    if(t-k>0)
        printf("%u\n",a[t-k]);
```

As `t` and `k` are both unsigned integers then the result of `t-k` is always  non-negative even if `t` is less than `k`. But the result can give a wong index for the array element `a[t-k]`

The else statement

```
    else
        printf("%u\n",a[t-k+n]);
```

is executed only when `t` is equal to `k`.:) But in this case the index of tha array `t-k+n` will be equal to n and refer to beyind the array.

```
printf("%u\n",a[t-k+n]);
```

Take into account that the condotion in the if statement

```
if(t-k>0)
```

could be substituted for

```
if ( t > k )
```

But in any case you should check that the resulted index of the outputted element will be valid.

Comment: The `else` statement is also invalid since when `t = k` then `a[t-k+n]` becomes `a[n]` which is outside the bounds of `a`.

Comment: You want `t>=k` in the condition.

Comment: @Toby Speight  I wrote a condition that corresponds to condition t - k > 0 provided that it would be valid.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow your answer makes mine seem too poor, here is my +1. Do you think I should delete it?

Comment: @gsamaras  You should add a check that the result index is valid in your demonstrative program.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow that's a great idea, updated, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Since the code is small, this could be a good chance for starting using ***gdb***. That way, you may save yourself a lot of time. Here is an [introductory tutorial](http://www.cprogramming.com/gdbtutorial.html).

---

The problem lies here:

```
if(t-k>0) // <- HERE!
  printf("%u\n",a[t-k]);
else
  printf("%u\n",a[t-k+n]);
```

since `t` and `k` are unsigned integers. The problem will be exposed with some values for these variables. For example, I added a `printf()`, before that if-else statement and I got:

```
2
2
2
1
2
1
RESULT: -1
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

So, you can see that because the variables are unsigned integers, the result of `t-k` is ***always*** non-negative, as the result of an operation on unsigned integers, no matter what the values of `t` and `k` are.

As a solution, you could set these two variables into integers, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    unsigned int n,q,i;
    int t,k;
    scanf("%u %d %u",&n,&k,&q);
    unsigned int a[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%u",&a[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<q;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&t);
        printf("RESULT: %d\n", t-k);
        if(t-k>0)
            printf("%u\n",a[t-k]);
        else
            printf("%u\n",a[t-k+n]);
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

and now the output becomes:

```
2
2
2
1
2
1
RESULT: -1
2
```

and one can see, no segmentation fault occurs here and 2 is printed as expected.